# Deploying a web application using a context on tomcat 7

Tags: tomcat, deployment, war

Seems I can't figure out how to deploy a web application to a path I want on tomcat 7. Here are the details:

1. I have a war file called myapp.war which I want to be located under /home/user/myapp.war (not where tomcat is installed).
2. I would like to have it deployed on tomcat under the path /api/1/

If I place myapp.war directly under the webapps directory of tomcat it will deploy, but under the path /myapp, which is not what I need.
I'm also trying to avoid editing tomcat's server.xml file.

I understand there are ways to do it using context files, but anything I tried just didn't work, looks like I'm missing something. If someone could describe the precise configuration to have this working it will be most appreciated.

Thanks! Ariel

Answer (score 1):

This link has the explanation and how to do it.
http://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/howto/Tomcat_More.html

If you insist on using a webapp name that doesn't match the expected URL, then you must keep the webapp
*outside* of the  appBase directory, and create a conf/Catalina/[host]/[appName].xml file
containing a  element with a docBase attribute that points to the deployed location.  Note that
[appName] above is what you want to appear in the URL.

Comment: Thanks for the link which contains useful information. However I still can't make it work. I'm trying to use the recommended approach - drop myapp.war file under the default webapps directory. However, I've added a context.xml file inside the war file, under the META-INF dir, which contains the following:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context path="/api/1" />
However, tomcat ignores it, and creates /myapp as the path, instead of /api/1. Any idea why this doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and I tried the following apparoach and it worked for me:
 
Rename war file to match the context path and replace `"/"` with `"#"`. For example: `api#1#myapp.war`

If you are using the context.xml then also you will have to rename it to `api#1#myapp.xml`

I hope it works for you as well. If you find other solution please share.